# Class cast exception HashSet

Tags: java, casting

Im getting an error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.HashSet` at line:     `(HashSet<String>) pos[targetPos3]).contains(word)`.

```
 public void search(String word, Object[] root){
    int targetPos1;
    int targetPos2;
    Object[] pos = root;

    targetPos1 = word.charAt(0) -'a';
    targetPos2 = word.charAt(1) -'a';
    int targetPos3 = word.charAt(2) - 'a';

    if(root[targetPos1]==null){
        System.out.println("1st letter NOT FOUND");
    }
    else{
         pos = (Object[]) root[targetPos1];
         if(pos[targetPos2]==null){
             System.out.println("2nd letter NOT FOUND");
         }
         else{
             if( ((HashSet<String>) pos[targetPos3]).contains(word)){
                 System.out.println("Word FOUND: " + word);
                 System.out.println(pos[targetPos3]);//output children
             }
             else{
                 System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
             }
         }
    }//end of else

}
```

Comment: Where do you call this method? What is root?

Answer (score 1):

`pos` is Object and you are trying to convert it `HashSet<String>` and it raised `ClassCastException`.

It is definite that `pos[targetPos3]` not a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

`Object[] pos = root;`

and

`(HashSet<String>) pos[targetPos3]`

`pos[targetPos3]` must not be a `HashSet<String>`. It is impossible to answer your question further without knowing what the Object[] array actually contains (why is it so un-specific?) and what you are intending to do.

Answer (score 1):

Please try debugging the code and check the data type of word.. from error log it is showing that the data type of word is object (it may be String or something else) and you are trying to assign it to HashSet..

Answer (score 1):

From your code and exception actually you have an Object[] at pos[targetPos3].

You cannot cast that to HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

You have, by the looks of things an `Object[][]` that is passed in as `root`.

You get one of the `Object[]` (the one at `targetPos1`).

Then you get one of the `Object` from that (the one at `targetPos3`).

This `Object` you then try and cast to a `HashSet<String>`, this throws a `ClassCastException`.

From the exception is looks like that `Object` is actually another `Object[]` (`[Ljava.lang.Object;` cannot...) so you would seem to have an `Object[][][]` passed in as root. Or at least some elements of the second dimension array are `Object[]`.

I would suggest you either do an `instanceof` check before casting or, preferably, work out what that data structure you are passing in actually is and make it into a data transfer object rather than a multidimensional array that even your don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
if ((HashSet<String>) pos[targetPos3]).contains(word))
```

But you try this:

```
private class ArrayTools
{
    public static<T> boolean contains (T [] array, T key)
    {
        for (T item : array)
        {
            if (item.equals(key))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

then you can do it like this:

```
if (ArrayTools.contains(pos[targetPos3], word))
```

Note: you can't use it with primitives.

Comment: @user1747976 if you are using java standard types like `String`, then no need .. don't forget to replace `Object[]pos = root;` with `HashSet<String>[]pos = root;`